# Extending ruby object; extend_object callback prevents instance methods from being extended

Tags: ruby, object, module, extend

Having some trouble extending an object instance with a module, specifically when I define an extend_object callback in the Module class.  My understanding is that when you do something like:

(s = String.new).extend SomeModule

The SomeModule extend_object callback is called.  This seems to be the case, but when I include a callback, none of the instance methods defined in SomeModule are visible in the object.  Some code should better explain this:

```
module M1
  def self.extend_object(o)
  end

  def test_method
    true
  end
end

module M2
  def test_method
    true
  end
end

(x = String.new).extend(M1)
(y = String.new).extend(M2)
```

Then,

```
x.methods.include?("test_method")
=> false
y.methods.include?("test_method")
=> true
```

More specifically,

```
x.singleton_methods
=> []
y.singleton_methods
=> ["test_method"]
```

Any ideas?

Reference:

```
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M001660
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000337
```

Answer (score 10):

You should use the `extended` callback rather than overriding `extend_object`.  The first is called when an object is extended by your module.  The latter is called to actually extend the object.  It's like the difference between `included` and `append_features`.

Here's an example:

```
module M1
  def self.extended(base)
    puts "extended object #{base.inspect}"
  end

  def test_method
    true
  end
end
```

Then:

```
>> (x = String.new).extend(M1)
extended object ""
=> ""

>> x.methods.include?("test_method")
=> true
```

Answer (score 3):

Got some help from a colleague, and realized I need to call `super` else it's a noop. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Also you need to use the symbol, because method name is symbol

```
module M1
  def self.extend_object(o)
    super
  end

  def test_method
    true
  end
end

(x = String.new).extend(M1)

x.methods.include?(:test_method)  #=> true
```